# Spring Boot does not inject @Autowired repository into netty classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, netty

I have a Spring Boot application with the following structure:

- com.test (Root Class)
- com.test.jpa (JPA Entities and Repositories)
- com.test.netty (netty TCP server)

The root class is:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test"})
//@EnableJpaRepositories
//@EntityScan
public class MyApplication {
...
```

The Netty Server:

```
package com.test.netty;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class NettyServer {

    private EventLoopGroup boss = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    private EventLoopGroup work = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    @PostConstruct    
    public void start() {
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(boss, work).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
//                  .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)).childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true).childHandler(new ServerChannelInit());
        try {
            ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind().sync();
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                log.info("Netty Server Started!");

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            log.error("Error Initializing Netty Server. Error: " + ie.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() throws InterruptedException {
        boss.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        work.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        log.info("Netty Server Shut Down!");
    }
```

and:

```
public class ServerChannelInit extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ch.pipeline().addLast("mainHandler", new ServiceHandler());
        
    }
```

and:

```
package com.test.netty;
@Component
public class ServiceHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private SomeEntity en;

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository sr;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    // Read data and persist some entitys using injected repository
```

And repository:

```
package com.test.jpa;

//@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, BigInteger> {

}
```

The problem is: Repository is not injected into com.test.netty classes. I use it in root class and in JUnit tests without any problem.
I added @Repository to the repository and also added repo packages in @EnableJPARepositories but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Repository is commented out if you remove the comment signs it should work.

Comment: It doesn't work even by adding @Repository

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace?

Comment: @BarHoshen The exception is NullPointerException and the stacktrace does not contain any useful information. The exception thrown because "sr" is null.

Comment: You've left out the most important part of your code which is the `...` after `ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();`. How are you registering the handler with the `ServerBootstrap`? There is no `ServiceHandler` autowired into `NettyServer` (unless there's setter injection going on and you also left that part out), so how are you obtaining the reference to the `ServiceHandler` bean?

Comment: @crizzis I edited my question and added the whole class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you're creating an instance of `ServiceHandler` yourself rather than using the bean instance Spring creates for you, *of course* no dependency injection will be performed. You need to inject the `ServiceHandler` bean into `ServerChannelInit` as well as make `ServerChannelInit` a `@Component` itself:

```
@Component
public class ServerChannelInit extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{

    private final ServiceHandler handler;

    public ServerChannelInit(ServiceHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ch.pipeline().addLast("mainHandler", handler);
        
    }
    ...
}
```

and then inject `ServerChannelInit` into `NettyServer`:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class NettyServer {

    private final ServerChannelInit channelInit;

    public NettyServer(ServerChannelInit channelInit) {
        this.channelInit = channelInit;
    }

    private EventLoopGroup boss = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    private EventLoopGroup work = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    @PostConstruct    
    public void start() {
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(boss, work).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
//                  .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)).childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true).childHandler(channelInit);
...
}
```

Comment: Yup it worked. Thanks so much. I also added @Component to ServiceHandler.

Comment: Another note to add, @Sharable annotation should be added to ServiceHandler.

Answer (score 0):

I just executed with the followings, just add `@SpringBootApplication` in your main class. Uncomment `@Repository`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, BigInteger> {

     void foo();
}


@Component
public class SampleRepo implements SomeRepository{

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Called...." );
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class ServiceHandler  {


    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository sr;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public void call(){
        sr.foo();

    }
}
```

It works!

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately my code does not run correctly. I think there is a problem in the configurations of netty classes.

Comment: I see your ```@service``` annotations in ```NettyServer``` class is just using ```@PostConstruct```  method and 2 objects are created.